# binding keyboard events tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, binding

Still quite new at python , i'm learning tkinter.
I would like to use keyboard events rather than mouse events for some fonction.
However keyboard events do not work although mouse events do.
here is a very simple example of what is not working. Using button 1 with the mouse and pressing key 'z on the keyboard should do the same, but the keyboard does nothing. I have tried to read tkinter documentation but didn't find the answer.

thanks for your help

```
from tkinter import *

class Pipi(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,width=400,height=400,bg='red')
        self.pack()

        self.bind("<z>",self.do)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.do)


    def do(self,event):
        print('la vie est belle')



root=Tk()
Pipi(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to `Frame` widget not having the focus. With the mouse event, it works seemingly different. There can be a couple of workarounds:

1. Grabbing the focus before the event happens
2. binding to something else

---

To achieve the first, simply add:

```
    self.focus_set()
```

somewhere inside `__init__`.

---

To achieve the second, replace:

```
self.bind("<z>",self.do)
```

with:

```
self.master.bind('<z>', self.do)
```

Comment: thanks a lot , works perfectly.
i guess it's the master widget who had the focus then.

Comment: @ericparis Looks that way, but I'd be happy if someone could confirm.